# Regex exclude group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a simple string `word anotherword wordanother AS-00009405 at 01.10.2015 0:00:00`, and i want exlude all data that not match my regex `([A|S]{2}-?[0-9]+)` How i can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like below.

Globally Find: `(?=[\S\s])(?:(?![AS]{2}-?[0-9]+)[\S\s])*((?:[AS]{2}-?[0-9]+)?)`
Replace '`$1`' (I put an extra space to separate the substrings)

[Formatted and tested:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 (?= [\S\s] )                         # Assert any character exists ahead
                                      # (this avoids working for nothing)

 (?:                                  # Cluster group 
      (?! [AS]{2} -? [0-9]+ )              # Assert, Not 'my substring'
      [\S\s]                               # Ok, grab any character (advance 1 char position)
 )*                                   # Optional, do 0 to many times

 (                                    # (1 start)
      (?: [AS]{2} -? [0-9]+ )?             # Optional, advance past 'my substring'
 )                                    # (1 end)
```

Sample input:

```
word anotherword wordanother AS-00009405 at 01.10.2015 0:00:00, and i want exlude all data that 

word anotherword wordanother AS-00009405 at 01.10.2015 0:00:00, and i want exlude all data that 

word anotherword wordanother AS-00009405 at 01.10.2015 0:00:00, and i want exlude all data that
```

Output:

```
AS-00009405 AS-00009405 AS-00009405
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't say in which language, but in PHP you can do this:

```php
$word = "word anotherword wordanother AS-00009405 at 01.10.2015 0:00:00";
$pattern = "/.*([A|S]{2}-?[0-9]+).*/";

$word = preg_replace($pattern, "$1", $word);

// $word contains: AS-00009405
```

You'll have to change your Regex a little though, by including `.*` at the beginning and at the end.